# Function uses field before it has the time to be initialized

Tags: java, swing, locale

I am making an UI project with a locale getter, but the UI claims the locale wasn't initialized when it was called.

Here's `main()`:

```java
public static void main(String[] argv)
{
    initLocale();
    refreshData();
    MainWindow.exec();
}
```

The `initLocale()` static function gets locale settings through a *properties* file, setting a HashMap of strings.
The `refreshData()` function doesn't interest us, and the `MainWindow.exec()` calls the main window.

Here's the `exec()` function:

```java
public static void exec()
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The constructor calls the `initialize()` function there:

```java
private void initialize()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    
    try
    {
        frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("icons/icon.png")));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {}
    
    frame.setTitle(Main.getLocalizedName("title").replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "")); // < The error is thrown here
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    
    panel = new JPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
    
    // Rest of the function
}
```

First an icon is imported, then I try to set the title as the locale settings. Every time i try this, a `NullPointerException` is thrown.

Logically, the `initLocale()` function should have done its job before the window would have been initialized, but it's not the case. Could somebody help me here?

Comment: All updates to the GUI should be done on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Put all the code in the invokeLater. This will make sure the code executes sequentially on the EDT.

Comment: @camickr Could you provide an example please?

Comment: aaah, it was at the `exec()`... sorry! I understand now!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @camickr for the tip!

I had to move the locale code to my `exec()` function to implement the function:

```java
public static void exec()
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                window.frame.setTitle(Main.getLocalizedName("title").replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""));
                // Other locales
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```